# Issue with null key/value's when accessing a map/vector from a callback generated from ESP32 bluetooth library

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth, microcontroller, esp32

I am trying to fire a function every time an ESP32 node receives a certain char. I can receive the data and parse the char out of a packet structure I have made. I register all my actions in a map of type <char,callback_function>, where

`typedef void (*callback_function)(void);`

The idea being that I link all the chars to their respective functions. I can then parse a char out and find the pointer to the function I want to fire easily. The only downside is I have to keep a reference to a global object to access this map from within the `bluetooth_callback`. I've been testing this for almost 2 days now, and I've written some example code without the espressif APIs. On its own, my code seems to work fine and it runs on the ESP32 aswell. But if I let the bluetooth_callback get called after registering it with the espressif API (ie. let a real bluetooth event to fire the callback), the behavior becomes undefined. The size of the map is still correct with the number of pairs I have added to it, but all of the values and keys are null or undefined, and if I try to access them I get a Guru Meditation Error. I have been trying to solve this problem a lot, and the behaviour is very strange to me. If I call the callback manually then everything seems to work, but if I let it get called by a bluetooth event, I get undefined behavior and crashes. I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong c++ wise or if I this is an issue specific to the esp32. I could be making a dumb mistake. I have attached my Arduino script, the header and cpp files of the library I was working on, and a sample application that should show what I am trying to do. Thank you for your help.

#### Hardware:

Board:                              ESP32 Dev Module (Sparkfun ESP32 thing)

Core Installation version:          1.0.3

IDE name:                           Arduino IDE

Flash Frequency:                    40Mhz

PSRAM enabled:                                    no

Upload Speed:                   115200

Computer OS:                                        Windows 10

#### Backtrace

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 0 register dump:
PC      : 0x400014e8  PS      : 0x00060430  A0      : 0x800d2410  A1      : 0x3ffcf1a0  
A2      : 0x000000fe  A3      : 0x000000fc  A4      : 0x000000ff  A5      : 0x0000ff00  
A6      : 0x00ff0000  A7      : 0xff000000  A8      : 0x800d2228  A9      : 0x3ffcf170  
A10     : 0x3ffbed90  A11     : 0x3f40148b  A12     : 0x3f40148b  A13     : 0x0000ff00  
A14     : 0x00ff0000  A15     : 0xff000000  SAR     : 0x00000010  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x000000fc  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xfffffffb  

Backtrace: 0x400014e8:0x3ffcf1a0 0x400d240d:0x3ffcf1b0 0x400d242d:0x3ffcf1d0 0x400d14a2:0x3ffcf1f0 0x400d1501:0x3ffcf210 0x400df881:0x3ffcf230 0x400d8362:0x3ffcf280 0x4008d83d:0x3ffcf2b0
```

#### Decoded:

PC: 0x400014e8
EXCVADDR: 0x000000fc

```
Decoding stack results
0x400d240d: Print::write(char const*) at C:\Users\Jake Booth\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.3\cores\esp32/Print.h line 66
0x400d242d: Print::print(char const*) at C:\Users\Jake Booth\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.3\cores\esp32\Print.cpp line 89
0x400d14a2: NodeESP::act_message(char*) at C:\Users\Jake Booth\Documents\Arduino\libraries\NodeESP\NodeESP.cpp line 336
0x400d1501: NodeESP::bluetooth_callback(esp_spp_cb_event_t, esp_spp_cb_param_t*) at C:\Users\Jake Booth\Documents\Arduino\libraries\NodeESP\NodeESP.cpp line 176
0x400df881: btc_spp_cb_handler at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32/esp-idf-public/components/bt/bluedroid/btc/profile/std/spp/btc_spp.c line 152
0x400d8362: btc_task at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32/esp-idf-public/components/bt/bluedroid/btc/core/btc_task.c line 110
0x4008d83d: vPortTaskWrapper at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32/esp-idf-public/components/freertos/port.c line 143
```

I've highlighted line 336 below to show you easily which one it is.

#### Arduino Sketch

```
#include "NodeESP.h"

#define LED_PIN 5

#define TOGGLE_LED_CHAR 'l'
#define TURN_ON_LED_CHAR 'p'

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  pinMode(LED_PIN,OUTPUT);

  char l = TOGGLE_LED_CHAR;
  char p = TURN_ON_LED_CHAR;

  esp_spp_cb_param_t ex_param;
  ex_param.data_ind.data = (uint8_t*)l;
  ex_param.data_ind.len = 1;
  //ex_param_ptr = *ex_param;

  NodeESP node_esp;
  node_esp.add_func(&p, toggle_LED);
  node_esp.add_func(&l, turn_on_LED);
  node_esp.begin("TEST_1");
//Just calling it manually works, but when the espressif API calls it I get undefined behaviour.
//  NodeESP::bluetooth_callback(ESP_SPP_DATA_IND_EVT,&ex_param);
}

void toggle_LED()
{
  Serial.println("toggle_LED()");
}

void turn_on_LED()
{
  Serial.println("turn_on_LED()");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while(1)
  {
    vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}
```

#### NodeESP.h

```
/*
  NodeESP.cpp - Library for automatically connecting to and using esp32 microcontrollers
  Created by Jacob Booth 11/9/2020
*/

#ifndef NodeESP_h
#define NodeESP_h

#include "Arduino.h"

#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <map>

#include "esp_bt_main.h"
#include "esp_bt_device.h"
#include "esp_spp_api.h"
#include "esp_gap_bt_api.h"

//---Define buffer constants--------------------------
#define RCV_BUF_SIZE 128
#define TX_BUF_SIZE 256

//---Define communication constants-------------------
#define RFCOMM_CHANNEL 1
#define RFCOMM_MAX_FRAME_SIZE 0xffff

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! please run 'make menuconfig' to enable it
#endif

class NodeESP
{
  public:
    //Constructor
    NodeESP();
    
    //Begin
    bool begin(const char *_name);

    //Typedef
    typedef void (*callback_function)(void);

    //Variables
    uint32_t bt_handle;
    const char *_name;
    std::map<char*, callback_function> funcs;
    
    char rx_buf[RCV_BUF_SIZE];
    char tx_buf[RCV_BUF_SIZE];
    WiFiServer server;
    WiFiClient client;
    
    //Generic
    void add_func(char* command, callback_function func);
    void act_message(char* trigger);

    //Bluetooth
    void bluetooth_write(char *buf, int len);
    bool bluetooth_spp_init();
    bool bluetooth_init(const char *deviceName);
    
    static char parse_data(uint8_t *rcvd, uint16_t len);
    static void bluetooth_callback(esp_spp_cb_event_t event, esp_spp_cb_param_t *param);

    String toString(const IPAddress & address);
  private:
};
#endif
```

#### NodeESP.cpp

```
/*
  NodeESP.cpp - Library for automatically connecting to and using esp32 microcontrollers
  Created by Jacob Booth 11/9/2020
*/

#include "Arduino.h"

#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <map>

#include "esp_bt_main.h"
#include "esp_bt_device.h"
#include "esp_spp_api.h"
#include "esp_gap_bt_api.h"

#include "NodeESP.h"

using namespace std;

//---State Machine Variables---
//State enum that helps the state machine track its way through 
//connecting to wifi.
enum state_t {
  UNDEFINED,
  DISCONNECTED,
  WIFI_CON,
  SERVER_CON
};

enum comm_t {
  s,
  NONE,
  WIFI,
  BLUETOOTH,
  q
};

//The current communication protocol we are using
comm_t cur_comm = s;

//The current state
state_t cur_state = UNDEFINED;


char tx_buf[TX_BUF_SIZE];
char rx_buf[RCV_BUF_SIZE];

//---Wifi
WiFiServer server(0);
WiFiClient client;

//---Bluetooth
uint32_t bt_handle;

void* example_obj;

//---Main Init--------------------------------------------------------
NodeESP::NodeESP()
{
  this->_name = "default";
  example_obj = (void*)this;
}

bool NodeESP::begin(const char *_name)
{
  this->_name = _name;
  
  //For testing set the current communication method to bluetooth
  cur_comm = BLUETOOTH;
    
  switch (cur_comm)
  {
    case UNDEFINED:
      return false;
      break;
      
    case NONE:
      return false;
      break;
      
    case WIFI:
      return true;
      break;
      
    case BLUETOOTH:
      if (!this->bluetooth_init(_name))
      {
        return false;
      }
      break;
  }
  return true;
}

//---Bluetooth Functions--------------------------------
bool NodeESP::bluetooth_init(const char *deviceName)
{
  //Start Bluetooth
  if (!btStart()) 
  {
    return false;
  }
  
  //Start BlueDroid (bluetooth stack)
  if (esp_bluedroid_init()!= ESP_OK) 
  {
    return false;
  }
  
  //Enable BlueDroid
  if (esp_bluedroid_enable()!= ESP_OK) 
  {
    return false;
  }
  
  //Set device name
  esp_bt_dev_set_device_name(deviceName);
  
  //Set sannable and discoverable
  esp_bt_gap_set_scan_mode(ESP_BT_SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE);
  
  //Init spp server
  if (!this->bluetooth_spp_init())
  {
    return false;
  }
  //Set send bytes to the correct callback
  //send_bytes = write_bluetooth;
  return true;
}

bool NodeESP::bluetooth_spp_init()
{
  if (esp_spp_register_callback(&bluetooth_callback) != ESP_OK)
  {
    return false;
  }
  
  if (esp_spp_init(ESP_SPP_MODE_CB) != ESP_OK)
  {
    return false;
  }

  if (esp_spp_start_srv(ESP_SPP_SEC_NONE, ESP_SPP_ROLE_SLAVE, 1, "") != ESP_OK)
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

void NodeESP::bluetooth_write(char *buf, int len)
{
  esp_spp_write(bt_handle, len, (uint8_t*)buf);
}

void NodeESP::bluetooth_callback(esp_spp_cb_event_t event, esp_spp_cb_param_t *param)
{
  switch (event)
  {
    case ESP_SPP_SRV_OPEN_EVT:
    {
      NodeESP* self = (NodeESP*) example_obj;
      self->bt_handle = param->srv_open.handle;
      break;
    }  
    case ESP_SPP_CL_INIT_EVT:
      esp_bt_gap_set_scan_mode(ESP_BT_SCAN_MODE_NONE);
      break;
    case ESP_SPP_OPEN_EVT:
      break;
    case ESP_SPP_DATA_IND_EVT:
    {
      NodeESP* self = (NodeESP*) example_obj;
      //char trig = self->parse_data(param->data_ind.data, param->data_ind.len);
      self->act_message((char*)param->data_ind.data);
      break;
    }
    case ESP_SPP_CLOSE_EVT:
      esp_bt_gap_set_scan_mode(ESP_BT_SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE);
    case ESP_SPP_WRITE_EVT:
      break;
    case ESP_SPP_CONG_EVT:
      break;
  }
  return;
}

//---Parsing functions-------------------------------
//TODO: Add circular buffer
char NodeESP::parse_data(uint8_t *rcvd, uint16_t len)
{
  
  char body_buf[RCV_BUF_SIZE];
  uint8_t len_buf[2];
  uint8_t rcvd_bytes = 0;
  uint8_t recive_stage = 0;

  uint16_t calc_len = 0;
  
  //Loop through each char recieved
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    uint8_t cur_char = rcvd[i];
    rcvd_bytes++;
 
    //If we haven't recieved the length or body
    //And we recieve a start delim
    if (recive_stage == 0 && cur_char == 0x7E)
    {
      //We are ready to read the length of the message (next 2 bytes)
      recive_stage = 1;
      rcvd_bytes = 0;
    } 
    else if (recive_stage == 1)//If we are recieving the length
    {      
      //Next two bytes get stored in the length buffer
      len_buf[rcvd_bytes - 1] = cur_char;
            
      //If we have recieved the 2 length bytes
      if (rcvd_bytes == 2)
      {
        //Decode the length
        calc_len = ((uint16_t)len_buf[0]) << 8 | (uint16_t)len_buf[1];
                
        //Ready to recieve the body
        recive_stage = 2;
        rcvd_bytes = 0;
      }
    } 
    else if (recive_stage == 2)//If we are recieving the body
    {
      //Store the recieved bytes
      body_buf[rcvd_bytes - 1] = cur_char;

      if (rcvd_bytes == calc_len)
      {
        //Reset
        rcvd_bytes = 0;
        recive_stage = 0;

        return(cur_char);
      }
    }
  }
  return '/';
}

void NodeESP::add_func(char* command, callback_function func)
{
  Serial.println("Added new callback...");
  std::pair<char*, callback_function>* new_pair = new std::pair<char*, callback_function>(command,func);
  this->funcs.insert(*new_pair);
}

void NodeESP::act_message(char* trigger)
{  
  Serial.println("[act message]");
  Serial.print("funcs.size() = ");
  Serial.print(this->funcs.size()); //Always returns the correct size all of the time
  Serial.println("");
  
  for  (std::map<char*, callback_function>::iterator it = this->funcs.begin();
        it != this->funcs.end(); 
        ++it)
  {
    Serial.print("funcs[i].first = ");
    Serial.print(it->first); //Line 336, accessing the first element of the iterator
    Serial.println("");       //This works properly when I don't call the function through the callback.
    if (trigger == it->first)
    {
        (it->second)();
    }
  }
}


String NodeESP::toString(const IPAddress & address)
{
  return String(address[0]) + "." + address[1] + "." + address[2] + "." + address[3];
}
```

#### Example Program

Here is an example program that shows what I want to happen and that it works correctly.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
//Global object to access the instance from within static function

using namespace std;


class example
{
  public:

    example();
    void begin();
    typedef void (*callback_function)(void);
    std::map<char, callback_function> funcs;

    void add_func(char command, callback_function func);
    void do_something(char trigger);
    
    static void example_callback(char cb);
};

void* example_obj;

example::example()
{
  example_obj = (void*)this;
}

void example::begin()
{
  //Set up everything to do with external library, peripherals, ect...

  //Register the callback with the library
  //register_callback(&example_callback);
}

//Static func that does something
void example::example_callback(char cb)
{
  //Have to do this because the args need to match the library's requirements
  example* self = (example*) example_obj;

  //Do some processing...
  self->do_something(cb);
}

//Add a function pointer and its command char to the vector
void example::add_func(char command, callback_function func)
{
    std::pair<char, callback_function>* new_pair = new std::pair<char, callback_function>(command,func);
    this->funcs.insert(*new_pair);
}

//This function is called from the callback
void example::do_something(char trigger)
{
  cout << "funcs.size() = "<< (this->funcs.size())<<"\n"; //Always returns the correct size all of the time

  for  (std::map<char, callback_function>::iterator it = this->funcs.begin();
        it != this->funcs.end(); 
        ++it)
  {
    cout << "funcs[i].first = "<< (it->first)<<"\n";
    if (trigger == it->first)
    {
        (it->second)();
    }
  }
}

void callback()
{
    cout << "Callback Called!";
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Starting program...\n";
    
    cout << "Creating example object...\n";
    example ex;
    
    cout << "Adding some callbacks...\n";
    ex.add_func('x',callback);
    ex.add_func('y',callback);
    ex.add_func('z',callback);
    
    cout << "Firing callback...\n";
    example::example_callback('z');
}
```

Comment: While I'm not sure this is your only problem (thus not posting it as an answer), your map is of type `<char*, callback>` and the `char *` pointers you are using in your sketch are pointers to local variables to the `setup` function so referencing them outside that function later (like when you're in your callback after setup has returned) is undefined; while it's fine when you explicitly call the callback from the `setup` function. Your example code doesn't have this problem as it's a map of type `<char, callback>` which is probably when you want to use in your sketch.

Comment: @Unn I've changed this but unfortunately the behavior is the same. The only thing I can think of is an error between unsigned chars and signed chars, or somehow the reference gets deleted. I'm going to change the software to not use dynamic memory for storing the callback table and put runtime configuration as a future feature.